# Me gustaria resolver esto en PHP

Tags: php

Deberás escribir un programa que lea el archivo  Json  donde se encuentran las compras de un cliente y calcule la fecha de posible recompra de los productos que compró (solo los que compró al menos 2 veces).

Para obtener la fecha de recompra de un producto: hay que analizar cada cuanto tiempo vuelve a comprar ese producto. Luego sumarle ese tiempo a la fecha de última compra del producto. Entonces vas a calcular una fecha de recompra por producto.

Con el siguiente codigo de Json:

```
{
       "customer": {
          "purchases": [
               {
       "number": "B001-002306",
       "date": "2020-01-01",
       "products": [
      {
        "sku": "101",
        "name": "Cat Chow 1KG"
      },
      {
        "sku": "102",
        "name": "Tidy Cats 2KG"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "number": "B001-002307",
    "date": "2020-01-15",
    "products": [
      {
        "sku": "103",
        "name": "Royal canin cat ultra light pouch"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "number": "B001-002308",
    "date": "2020-02-01",
    "products": [
      {
        "sku": "101",
        "name": "Cat Chow 1KG"
      } ]
  },
  {
    "number": "B001-002309",
    "date": "2020-03-01",
    "products": [
      {
        "sku": "101",
        "name": "Cat Chow 1KG"
      },
      {
        "sku": "102",
        "name": "Tidy Cats 2KG"
      }
      
    ]
      }
      ]
     }
       }
```

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
$datos_clientes = file_get_contents("purchases.json");
$json_clientes = json_decode($datos_clientes, true);


function fechasDeCompra($arrayDeBusqueda){

$nuevaArray = array();

    foreach ($arrayDeBusqueda['customer']["purchases"] as $subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "products"){
            
            $nuevaArray[]=$value;


        }

    }
}
    return $nuevaArray;
}


var_dump(fechasDeCompra($json_clientes));
```

No tengo idea como encarar el ejercicio, no se como unir las fechas con productos que se hayan pedido mas de una vez

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y qué problemas tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Suerte. Saludos

Comment: Lo que hice fue pasar el codigo Json a un array mediante lo siguiente   

`$datos_clientes = file_get_contents("purchases.json");`
`$json_clientes = json_decode($datos_clientes, true);`

pero despues al intentar recorrer el array de esta forma

`foreach ($arrayDeBusqueda['customer'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "date"){
   array_push($nuevaArray, $value);

  }

 }
 return $nuevaArray;

}`
me da un array vacio

Comment: Aquí estás iterando sobre un array que no existe: `foreach ($arrayDeBusqueda['customer'] as $key => $value)` ... ¿ de dónde sacas `$arrayDeBusqueda`? Y, ese código tenía que ir de entrada en la pregunta.

Comment: `$arrayDeBusqueda` es un parametro de la funcion que cree para luego pasarle el array que quiera, perdon si lo subi mal es la priemra vez que uso esta pagina.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta poniendo el código que estás usando. No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer ni cómo lo estás haciendo. No podemos adivinar.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si quieres iterar sobre las compras, la forma correcta sería esta: `foreach ($json_clientes['customer']['purchases'] as $key => $value) { `  asumiendo que `$json_clientes` es tu json. El array de datos está realmente dentro de la clave `purchases` que a su vez está dentro de la clave `customer` Tú tienes que analizar la esctructura del JSON para saber cómo leerlo.

Comment: Claro entiendo para buscar las fechas entonces me conviene usar el foreach como me lo estas diciendo. Y para agregar los valores de las fechas a un array vacio esta bien el metodo que estoy utilizando?

Comment: Los niveles de datos en JSON se identifican por si están entre `{...}`  o entre `[...]`. En el primer caso sería un **objeto json**, en el segundo sería un **array json**. Entonces, si analizas la estructura, `customer` es un objeto json, porque delante de èl  hay `{` y `purchases` es un array, porque delante de él hay `[` Luego están los valores primarios, que pueden ser cadenas, enteros o booleanos y van entre comillas o fuera de ellas según el caso. Por ejemplo, `number` y `date` son una cadena. Eso es todo, no hay más misterio con JSON.

Comment: Mira te muestro lo que modifique  
`foreach ($arrayDeBusqueda['customer']["purchases"] as $subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "date"){
   array_push($nuevaArray, $value);


  }

 }
}
 return $nuevaArray;
}
`
Y ahora el array ya lo pude completar con las fechas

Comment: Ahora voy a intentar hacer la parte del promedio de fechas en un mismo producto, vuelvo a editar en cuanto tenga algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te dije en comentarios, mirando lo que hay delante de cada clave sabrás lo que es y decidirás la forma de leerlo:

- `{ ... }` representa un objeto JSON
- `[ ... ]` representa un array JSON
- `"....."` representa una cadena
- `999` representa un número
- `true` o `false` representa un booleano

Eso es todo, y ya tienes un doctorado en JSON.

Ahora, si analizas la estructura y no olvidas lo dicho más arriba, comprenderás que tu código debe escribirse así:

```
function fechasDeCompra($arrayDeBusqueda){
    /*Acostumbra a definir tus variables de forma explícita*/
    $nuevaArray=array();
    /*
       Los datos de purchases están anidados en customer
       y purchases es un array, porque delante de él hay un [
       por eso tenemos que abrir otro bucle para leer ese array
    */
    foreach ($arrayDeBusqueda['customer']['purchases'] as $purchases) { 
        foreach ($purchases as $key=>$value) {
            if ($key == "date"){ 
                /*Esto es mejor que array_push, pero puedes usar también éste*/ 
                $nuevaArray[]=$value;       
            }   
        }        
    }
    return $nuevaArray; 
}
```

Creo que con lo explicado, y analizando el código y los comentarios que he puesto en él, podrás ver los errores que estabas cometiendo.

---

### Agrupar las fechas

Aquí te muestro una versión del código donde se agrupan las fechas. En lo que expones en la pregunta el ejercicio te pide otras cosas que deberás intentar tú y si tienes problemas puedes plantearlos en una nueva pregunta.

Debo decir que hay formas más simples para hacer estos procesos complicados, pero tratándose de un ejercicio supongo que no te permitirán usar ciertas funciones, con la idea de que aprendas a trabajar primero con arrays directamente.

He puesto comentarios en el código, para que se entienda lo que se hace en cada momento.

```
function fechasDeCompra($arrayDeBusqueda){
    /*Acostumbra a definir tus variables de forma explícita*/
    $nuevaArray=array();

    /*
        Vamos a recorrer el array de purchases que hay en customer
        Aplicando lo aprendido en el doctorado sobre JSON, más arriba
    */
    foreach ($arrayDeBusqueda['customer']['purchases'] as $purchases) { 
        foreach ($purchases as $key=>$value) {
            /*
                Este if es sólo por seguridad, en caso de que el JSON sea irregular
                y en algunos casos no tenga una propiedad products
            */
            if ($key == "products"){ 
                /*
                    Vamos a recorrer el array products que hay en nuestra variable $purchases
                    Volviendo al doctorado, si trazas la ruta customer->purchases->products
                    en el JSON, verás que delante de products hay un [, significa que es un array
                    Entonces, lo recorremos con un foreach
                */
                foreach ($purchases['products'] as $product){
                    /*
                        Según la lógica de lo que se te pide, y viendo la estructura del JSON
                        se comprende fácilmente que lo que identifica a los productos como únicos 
                        es el valor de la propiedad "sku", entonces aquí por cada $product['sku']
                        crearemos una nueva entrada en $nuevaArray 
                        y luego iremos metiendo un sub-array con las fechas, por eso hay un [] antes de =
                    */
                    $nuevaArray[$product['sku']][]=$purchases['date'];
                }
            }   
        }        
    }   
    return $nuevaArray; 
}
```

La salida del `var_dump()`  sería algo parecido a esto:

```
array(3) {
  [101]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2020-02-01"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2020-03-01"
  }
  [102]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2020-03-01"
  }
  [103]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-15"
  }
}
```

Como ves, hay un array asociativo de tres elementos distintos, que son los diferentes `sku` de los productos y luego están las fechas en que esos productos fueron comprados.

Otra cosa es que, dependiendo de lo que haya que hacer luego con las fechas, podría convenir mejor obtenerlas en forma de sub-arrays o en forma de valores llanos, todas dentro de un solo array. Eso ya escapa al propósito de esta respuesta.

Comment: Sisi ya logre ver mis errores en esta parte, como me aconsejas seguir para comparar los productos con la fecha de compra y ver si son iguales para calcular la proxima compra?

Comment: No tengo idea como encarar el ejercicio, no se como unir las fechas con productos que se hayan pedido mas de una vez

Comment: @Hugo revisa la respuesta editada, al final he puesto un código para agrupar las fechas, bajo la clave que identifica a los productos, que sería `sku`

Comment: Claro de la manera que esta agrupado me ayudaria para indentificar las fechas de compras de cada producto, ademas de la cantidad de veces en la cual se compro, muchas gracias por la ayuda en este ejercicio. Como ultima consulta te podria preguntar si hay alguna funcion para sacar la diferencia entre las fechas?

Comment: Sí, hay varias formas de hacer eso @Hugo. Para fechas te recomiendo que trabajes con la clase [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)  que tiene métodos para todo tipo de operaciones con fechas, desde lo más simple hasta operaciones avanzadas como calcular intervalos, períodos, etc. En cualquier caso, si tienes más problemas con otros aspectos concretos puedes abrir nuevas preguntas aquí (buscando primero si alguien no ha preguntado lo mismo o parecido), indicando el problema y la parte del código donde estás atascado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Cedano, me ayudaste muchisimo a aprender un poco mas de php que todavia me cuesta

Comment: @Hugo me alegro de que te haya servido, poco a poco se va aprendiendo y si hay dudas aquí hay mucha gente capaz que puede ayudarte. Si esta respuesta ha resuelto esta parte de tu pregunta, considera marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo.